# Creating a Character field directly on the remedy Regular form

Tags: java, remedy

How to create a field on remedy regular form using java api.how to add that field to the default adminstrator view.i had created the character field.only thing is the field created is not in the view.please tell me how to directly include in the view.that is to create directly on the regular form.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you add the field to the view by specifying the view display properties for the field and a VUI ID in the parameter ARDisplayInstanceList *dInstanceList.

If you look at the API guide for 7.6.04, on page 60 it reads:

**Defining field display properties**

Field display properties (AR_DPROP_*) fall into these categories:

- Those common to all schema views These display properties are
  collected in one ARPropList structure.
- Those specific to a
  particular schema view These display properties are collected in a
  series of additional ARPropList structures, each linked to a
  particular view (VUI). These view-specific property lists are
  represented by zero or more ARDisplayInstanceStruct structures.

I think you need to allocate and populate an ARDisplayInstanceList with the display properties and tie those display properties to the VUI ID.  When you pass it in either your call to ARCreateField() or ARSetField() it should add the field to the view specified by the VUI ID.

URL to 7.6.04 ARS API guide: https://docs.bmc.com/docs/download/attachments/165478929/ARS_CAPIGuide_7604.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1348735332000